# How to get a user not sharing a guild with? Discordjs

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

How do i get a user that not shares a guild with my bot in discord.js?

I already googled and found no awnser

Comment: Simple answer: you can't

Comment: @Chunkoforanges wrong

Comment: @MegaMix_Craft Not wrong, you can only get a user from a guild the bot is in, and the message guild

Comment: @Chunkoforanges interesting, but how my code does that then?

Comment: @Chunkoforanges Don't throw an answer without explanation, specially if it's wrong please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fetch/get a user that you don't share any guild with you can use [`Client.users.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=fetch) with parameter `force` set to `true` like in a code below:

```js
let user = await client.users.fetch("ID", { force: true, cache: true })
```

Comment: The `force` option is described as "Whether to skip the cache check and request the API" which is `true` by default